# Dynamic dashboard on ms excel

Tags: excel, dashboard

I have a workbook containing around 100 worksheets with identical structure and different values.

In each worksheet I have a column 'Status' that I want to display dynamically on the dashboard in a row.

E.g. for 1st worksheet, named Project A, the column:

```
Status
DONE
TODO
N/A
```

for 2nd worksheet, name Project B, the column:

```
Status
TODO
N/A
DONE
```

On the Dashboard (a new worksheet), it has to be displayed dynamically like this:

```
Project A  DONE TODO N/A
Project B  TODO N/A DONE
```

Any idea? :)

Comment: If you need to count values based on some criteria with sheet name based as parameter - consider using `COUNTIF()` and `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: @Taosique Why don't you post that comment as an answer? `Indirect` certainly should do the trick. All you need on the "Dashboard" sheet is a reference for "Project A" or "Project B" or whichever project should be displayed. So, the Dashboard sheet should be updated with all Project names. If you want to do this also dynamically then I (personally) would suggest the usage of a small VBA sub using `For Each sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` which updates with the `Worksheet_Activate()` event for the Dashboard sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to pass data across by entering this formula:
=Project A!C1
-C1 refers to the cell-
 on the cell you want to pass the data, however this is only a shortcut.